# Delete all times less than a specified value

Tags: r, if-statement, time, lubridate

This is probably a simple question however I am new to R and couldn't find an answer (or was googling the wrong thing).
I am currently working on a project which involves deleting all Time values that are less than 5 minutes. An example of the data is as follows with the times created using the "lubridate" package.

```
Time
19S
1M 24S
7M 53S
11M 6S
.
.
.
```

Now I wish to delete all values which are less than 5 minutes. Therefore the final dataset I wish to get is:

```
Time
7M 53S
11M 6S
.
.
.
```

Any help would be amazing!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
df <- df[df$time > ms('5:00'), ]
```

The result:

```
> df
    time value
3 7M 53S     3
4 11M 6S     4
```

Strangly enough, converting this to dplyr code; it doesn't work:

```
filter(df, time > ms('5:00'))
```

The result:

```
   time
1   53S
2 1M 6S
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

I asked a question about that and found a answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46363115/3526832). you get the good solution with:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>% 
  filter(time > as.numeric(ms('5:00'))) %>% 
  mutate(time = ms(paste0(floor(time/60),':',round((time/60 - floor(time/60))*60))))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(time = ms(c('0:19','1:24','7:53','11:6')), value = 1:4)
```

Comment: I've just deleted my previous comments as I have found the error in my ways. Your code is perfect. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
> library(lubridate)
> TimeData <- data.frame(Time = c("0M 19S", "1M 24S", "7M 53S", "11M 6S"))
> TimeData$Time <- ms(TimeData$Time)
> subset(TimeData, Time > "5M 00S")
    Time
3 7M 53S
4 11M 6S
```

Comment: This is basically the same approach as I posted earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your input :)