# dplyr's filter not working on lubridate's timeformats?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

When  trying to answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360218/delete-all-times-less-than-a-specified-value), I run against a problem with using `filter` from `dplyr`-package on a `lubridat`-period column.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(time = ms(c('0:19','1:24','7:53','11:6')), value = 1:4)
```

Using:

```
filter(df, time > ms('5:00'))
# or:
filter(df, time > '5M 00S')
```

results in the wrong output:

```
   time value
1   53S     3
2 1M 6S     4
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Applying the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853371/3526832) doesn't also result in the correct output:

```
> df %>% 
+   mutate(time = format(time, '%M:%S')) %>% 
+   filter(time > '05:00')
    time value
1    19S     1
2 1M 24S     2
3 7M 53S     3
4 11M 6S     4
```

But using vanilla R methods, do work:

```
> df[df$time > ms('5:00'), ]
    time value
3 7M 53S     3
4 11M 6S     4

> subset(df, time > ms('5:00'))
    time value
3 7M 53S     3
4 11M 6S     4
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my `dplyr` approach?

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem is that the correct rows are select (3 and 4) but the time columns has been altered?

Comment: Yes it is, I tried the same it seems to be interachanging M and S

Comment: could it have anything to do with tibbles and limitation in defining a date structure within them?

Comment: And there's a closed issue on github already https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2520

Comment: Open issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2432). Seems that the subsetting goes awry for this data type, without warning (in my case at least).

Comment: infact, the problem isn't filtering, it's how the df is displayed!

Comment: @Axeman It is indeed that the correct values are selected but the incorrect rows from the time column; also thank for the link to the github issue

Comment: A tidyverse solution would be `df %>%
   pull(time) %>%
   map_lgl(~ .> ms('5:00'))  %>%
   extract(df, ., )`

Comment: @akrun which other packages from tidyverse do i need for that? and why did you delete your answer? what do you think about my own solution?

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of different methods I get a `dplyr` only solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>% 
  filter(time > as.numeric(ms('5:00'))) %>% 
  mutate(time = ms(paste0(floor(time/60),':',round((time/60 - floor(time/60))*60))))
```

This results in the good result:

```
    time value
1 7M 53S     3
2 11M 6S     4
```